# Access previous value of association on record update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a "event" model that has many "invitations".  Invitations are setup through checkboxes on the event form.  When an event is updated, I wanted to compare the invitations before the update, to the invitations after the update.  I want to do this as part of the validation for the event.

My problem is that I can't seem to access the old invitations in any model callback or validation.  The transaction has already began at this point and since invitations are not an attribute of the event model, I can't use _was to get the old values.

I thought about trying to use a "after_initialize" callback to store this myself.  These callbacks don't seem to respect the ":on" option though so I can't do this only :on :update.  I don't want to run this every time a object is initialized.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Here is the code in my update controller:

```
  def update
  params[:event][:invited_user_ids] ||= []
  if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
    redirect_to @event
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
  end
```

My primary goal is to make it so you can add users to an event, but you can't not remove users.  I want to validate that the posted invited_user_ids contains all the users that currently are invited.

--Update
As a temporary solution I made use for the :before_remove option on the :has_many association.  I set it such that it throws an ActiveRecord::RollBack exception which prevents users from being uninvited.  Not exactly what I want because I can't display a validation error but it does prevent it.

Thank you,
Corsen

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to do the event and invitation updating?

Comment: I added the update action of my controller.  I'm using the auto generated invited_user_ids method to update the association.  I don't wan to allow it to delete any previous selections, instead only add new ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://localhost:8800/~brandan/sdoc/3.1.0-1.9/Rails/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)? Something like this:

```
def Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :no_invitees_removed

  def no_invitees_removed
    if invitees.changed? && (invitees - invitees_was).present?
      # ... add an error or re-add the missing invitees
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Edit:** I didn't notice that the OP already discounted `ActiveModel::Dirty` since it doesn't work on associations. My bad.

Another possibility is overriding the `invited_user_ids=` method to append the existing user IDs to the given array:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def invited_user_ids_with_guard=(ids)
    self.invited_user_ids_without_guard = self.invited_user_ids.concat(ids).uniq
  end
  alias_method_chain :invited_user_ids=, :guard
end
```

This should still work for you since `update_attributes` ultimately calls the individual `attribute=` methods.

---

**Edit:** @corsen asked in a comment why I used `alias_method_chain` instead of `super` in this example.

Calling `super` only works when you're overriding a method that's defined further up the inheritance chain. Mixing in a module or inheriting from another class provides a means to do this. That module or class doesn't directly "add" methods to the deriving class. Instead, it inserts itself in that class's inheritance chain. Then you can redefine methods in the deriving class without destroying the original definition of the methods (because they're still in the superclass/module).

In this case, `invited_user_ids` is not defined on any ancestor of `Event`. It's defined through metaprogramming directly on the `Event` class as a part of ActiveRecord. Calling `super` within `invited_user_ids` will result in a `NoMethodError` because it has no superclass definition, and redefining the method loses its original definition. So `alias_method_chain` is really the simplest way to acheive `super`-like behavior in this situation.

Sometimes `alias_method_chain` is overkill and pollutes your namespace and makes it hard to follow a stack trace. But sometimes it's the best way to change the behavior of a method without losing the original behavior. You just need to understand the difference in order to know which is appropriate.

Comment: No I wish I could.  But events has_many invitees.  It is not an attribute of the model, but an association.  It is not tracked by ActiveModel::Dirty.  Unless I am mistaken :)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I missed that in your original post. I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: This works and seems quite easy.  I am new to Ruby / Rails and have never heard to alias_method_chain before.  After doing some research I found there to be some debate on using this vs Inheritance / Super.  The Inheritance / Super seems like it would of been more complex to implement then this, so I'm going to accept the solution as it works well.  If you could elaborate on whether or not using Inheritance / Super would of been appropriate for this as well that would be great.  It would be very helpful for me, as I am new to Ruby / Rails.

Comment: It got too long for a comment :-)